# API REST desencadenar acción

Tags: api, rest, restful

No es la primera API REST que creo, pero las anteriores que he hecho eran muy de manual. En esta ocasión quiero que la API desencadena una acción que no solicita (get), no crea (post), no elimina (delete), ni actualiza (patch) un recurso.
Quiero que la acción simplemente envíe una notificación PUSH al destinatario deseado.

Lo que se me ha ocurrido sería:
"POST send" enviando al servidor un json con el destinatario y el mensaje. Y el estado de respuesta el 202.

Sé que no se deberían usar verbos en una API de este estilo, pero también he leído que a veces no se puede evitar estas acciones y que si son necesarias han de realizar pero con su debida explicación en la documentación.
Si alguien tiene una mejor solución para casos como estos en el que no se trabaja sobre los recursos sino que se quiere desencadenar una acción, estaría muy agradecido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

creo que en tu caso es correcto usar POST para enviar un mensaje a un usuario. Lo único que tienes que tener en cuenta de cara a mantener la filosofía REST es que las urls tienen que representar recursos. Llevado a tu caso, puedes hacer un POST a un endpoint que identifique el recurso que vas a crear. Por ejemplo:

`POST xxxxxservidorxxx/message/{iddestinatario}`

En el body pondrías el mensaje y en la respuesta puedes devolver, por ejemplo, el identificador del mensaje creado o de la cola o cualquier otra información que te sirva a ti para después.

Espero que esto te sirva